# How to disable click on <div> when <button> in <div> is clicked

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using ReactJS with React-Bootstrap and am rendering the following content:

```
<div onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)} className="container">
  <div className="content">
    <div className="list">
      ...
    </div>
    <Button onClick={this.deleteContent.bind(this)} 
      className="delete-content">X
    </Button>
    <Modal show={this.state.showModal} 
      onHide={this.closeModal.bind(this)}
      className="edit-content">
      ...
      <Button onClick={this.closeModal.bind(this)}
        className="close-modal">X
      </Button>
    </Modal>
  </div>
<div>
```

In `<div className="content">`, I am rendering a set of components, and when you click on the `<div className="Container">`, it will open the [`Modal`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-live) so you can edit the container's contents. There is a button to delete the container all together, which is inside the `<div className="container">`, as many containers will be rendered iteratively.

I am controlling whether the `Modal` is open with the component's `state`, where `this.openModal()` and `this.closeModal()` simply toggle a boolean that determines if the Modal should be shown (`this.state.showModal`).

My problem is: when I click the `Button` with `className="delete-content"` in the container, it also registers a click to open the `Modal`, because `<div className="container">` has an `onClick` property. Thus, when I delete containers, the app gets stuck thinking the `Modal` is open, even though it's not.

My first idea to fix this is to move the `onClick` property from the `<div className="container">` to `<div className="list">`, but I would like all of the space around the `<Button className="delete-content">` to be clickable, and if I move it to `list` it will restrict the clickable area.

Is it possible to somehow implement when the `delete-content` `Button` is clicked to temporarily disable the `onClick` property of the `<div className="container">`? Or any other ideas/fixes?

Comment: have you tried event.preventDefault() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because of [event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation). To fix the problem you need to use [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the event object.

```
handleDelete(event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  this.deleteContent()
}

<Button
  onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}
  className="delete-content">X
</Button>
```